# WTSQueryUserToken() gives ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have very common bug while call `WTSQueryUserToken()`. It returns false and `GetLastError()` show me `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`.
I tried set privileges(return OK) but i see same problem calling WTSQueryUserToken.

```
LUID luid;
    bRet = LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_TCB_NAME, &luid);
    if (!bRet) {
        hr = GetLastError();
        return hr;
    }

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES adjTokenPrivileges;// = { 0 };
    adjTokenPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    adjTokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    adjTokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    //CSampleCredential::Log("AdjustTokenPrivileges...");
    DWORD dwOldTPLen;
    bRet = AdjustTokenPrivileges(processToken, FALSE, &adjTokenPrivileges, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), &oldTokenPrivileges, &dwOldTPLen);
    if (bRet) {
        hr = GetLastError();
        if (hr == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        else if (hr == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED) {
            // Enabled by default
        }
    }
    else {
        hr = GetLastError();
        return hr;
    }
    //CSampleCredential::Log("WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId...");
    DWORD conSessId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    if (conSessId == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
        // There is no session attached to the console
        return ERROR_SUCCESS;
    }

    //impersonationToken = GetCurrentUserToken();
    //CSampleCredential::Log("WTSQueryUserToken...");
    bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(conSessId, &impersonationToken);
    if (!bRet) {
        hr = GetLastError();    
        return hr;
    }
```

Privileges for service also ok

[image: Share photos on twitter with Twitpic]

OS: Windows 7 64

Comment: Are you running in the local system context?

Comment: Yes and also tried to run it from LOCAL SERVICE account.